# ListView crashes the app in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm having a main menu which contains 4 different buttons. When you click a button a listview should appear. Finally, when you select one of the Item in the list, a new activity should start which show some text. When I click on the Tiffins button, the app closes instead of showing the listview. Please help.

Here is my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/icon"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/curries"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tiffins"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/curries"
    android:text="@string/Curries" 
    android:onClick="CurriesMenu"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tiffins"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/tiffins"
    android:text="@string/Tiffins" 
    android:onClick="TiffinsMenu"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:text="@string/Tiffins"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/curries"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/curries"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:text="@string/Curries"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/Snacks"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Snacks"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/snacks"
    android:text="@string/Snacks"
    android:onClick="SnacksMenu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/curries"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/Pindivantalu"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pindivantalu"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Snacks"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/pindivantalu"
    android:text="@string/Pindivantalu"
    android:onClick="PindivantaluMenu" />
```

activity_display_tiffinsmenu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayTiffinsmenu" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tiffins1"
    android:entries="@array/tiffinslist" >

</ListView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.andhrarecipies;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void TiffinsMenu(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayTiffinsmenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void CurriesMenu(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayCurriesmenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void SnacksMenu(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySnacksmenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void PindivantaluMenu(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayPindivantalumenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

DisplayTiffinsmenu.java

```
package com.example.andhrarecipies;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayTiffinsmenu extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //      setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_tiffinsmenu);

        ListView TiffinsMenu = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tiffinslist);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_display_tiffinsmenu, menu));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, "you have selected" + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_tiffinsmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from the exception thrown.

Comment: edit post and paste stack trace... I am guessing error is caused due to not mentioning activity in manifest

Answer (score 1):

When using `ListActivity`, your `activity_display_tiffinsmenu.xml`-layout must contain a `ListView` with the `android:id` attribute set to `@android:id/list` like this:

```
<ListView 
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hello Nick, Thanks for the suggestion. But If I do that, I'm getting the following error. "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@andriod:id/list')."